# Python to create multiple zip files for all in a folder

Tags: python, list, zip

Many files in a folder. I want to zip them all. Every 10 files will be added to a zip file.

```
import os, glob
import numpy as np
import zipfile

file_folder = "C:\\ABC\\DEF\\"

all_files = glob.glob(file_folder + "/*.*")

several_lists= np.array_split(all_files, 10)

for num, file_names in enumerate(several_lists):
    ZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(file_folder + str(num) + ".zip", "w" )

    for f in file_names:
        ZipFile.write(f, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        ZipFile.close()
```

The generated zip files contains also the paths, i.e. every zip file has a folder DEF in a folder ABC. The file themselves are in DEF.

I changed the line to:

```
ZipFile.write(os.path.basename(f), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Error pops for:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
```

How to correct it? Thank you.

Btw, is there a big difference in zip and rar file created by Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile.write` has a parameter `arcname` which allows explicitly providing an in-archive filename (by default it's the same as the on-disk path).

So just use `zip.write(f, arcname=os.path.basename(f))`.

Also for simplicity you could set the compression mode on the `zipfile.ZipFile`.

edit: and you can use the zipfile as a context manager for more reliability and less lines, and assuming Python 3.6 f-strings are nice:

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{file_folder}{num}.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    for f in file_names:
        zip.write(f, arcname=os.path.basename(f))
```

Comment: thank you for sharing knowledge! (btw the line "ZipFile.close()" needs to be moved to aligned with "ZipFile = ..." to make it right.)

Comment: indeed, or you can use the object as a *context manager* so you don't have to close it explicitly. I've edited my answer to add an example.